# How to display around 1000 images of 30 kb each in browser?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am trying to display around 1000 .jpg images of size 30 kb each (in average). Let me show the script first :

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    // database connection files
    include '../../lib/config.php';
    include '../../lib/opendb.php';

    set_time_limit (9999);  // to increase execution time for large upload database//

// allow access to page

    $showandsave = false; // choosen to view and save the images


    if(isset($_POST['submit_html'])){
    $showandsave = true;
    }

    $reportdatefrom = $_REQUEST['reportdatefrom'];
    $reportdateto = $_REQUEST['reportdateto'];
    // Prepare Constant Query for Master List
    $qry_const = "select";
    $qry_const .= " "."a.photoname";     
    $qry_const .= " "."from applicants a"; 
    $qry_const .= " "."where a.date_of_admission between '$reportdatefrom' and '$reportdateto'";

    $rs = mysql_query($qry_const) or die("Error Fetching List : ".mysql_error());           

            $gridsize = 10;
            $r = 0;
            echo "<table>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)){
            ++$r;
            if($r == 1 || ($r-1)%$gridsize == 0)
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><img src='".$row['photoname']."' height='100px' width='75px'/></td>";
            if($r%$gridsize == 0)
            echo "</tr>";
            }   
            echo "</table>";            
?>
```

While the number of images is less say around 20, no error occurs and the script works perfectly fine. But as the number exceeds say 200 then "500 Internal Server Error" is coming up. How to cop up with this situation? Please suggest a remedy.

Comment: Make thumbnails? What I mean is that a picture of 100x75 pixels can be around 1-3 KB, one-tenth the size you say they are. It would be useful if you tell us where the "500 Internal Server Error" shows up (the HTML file or in the images?).

Comment: Ok. But that will not compress the file, I think. @KIKO. I want to fetch the original size. Because my intention is to save the images in original size. The "500 Internal Server Error" shows up in the PHP file where the code is written.

Comment: I assume your code is for internal use only? You're using the depricated mysql library and you're putting user input directly into a SQL statement. This is highly insecure. See: SQL-injection.

Comment: I see no reason in the code why a  "500 Internal Server Error" should occur. I might be mistaken. Perhaps it is your server configuration? Help: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm

Comment: Yes KIKO. The code is for internal users only. The users are trusted. But I am not being able to figure out the problem why the large number of images fails to be diplayed on to the browser? Is there any size limit of html output for broswer using http?

Comment: No it certainly is not a size-limit of HTML output of PHP. There is no real limit on that.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your support KIKO. Let me check out the reference you provided. I will revert back with the outcomes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `500` error in PHP generally means the script crashed.  You need to know *why* it crashed.

That can sometimes be found in the web server error log or the php error log. You didn't say what platform (linux / apache / php? windows / iis / php? ) you're running on so it's hard to tell you where to look. Use your favorite search engine to ask for `php error log location linux apache` or whatever. Then look at the end of the error log.

While you're at it, look for `php.ini location linux apache`. There's a file called `php.ini` containing system limits.

I guess you are running out of time or RAM. PHP generally won't let you arbitrarily increase the time limit in the way you're trying: `set_time_limit (9999)`. The maximum time you can't exceed is the [max_execution_time setting in the `php.ini` file](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time). You may need to change it there.

Your PHP script may also be running out of memory. You'll need to change the [`memory_limit` setting](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) to fix that.

In the comments somebody mentioned the security danger of using the `mysql_` interface. That person was not kidding.  From comments in your code it looks like your site handles university applications. Now, nobody would dream of cracking a site like that. Would they? Would they? Be careful. Don't rely on a large institution's firewall.

Comment: Thanks Ollie Jones. I would not get any help more than what you offered. I am using Apache server. The application is using MySQL.